# Unable to get the correct name for annotation in the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, reflection, annotations, field

In the code below, the first loop iterate over the fields from a given class (passed to the view by the spring controller), and the second loop, iterate over the annotations of each field:

```
<x:Form>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${command['class'].declaredFields}" varStatus="status">
        <c:forEach var="item2" items="${item.declaredAnnotations}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${item2['class'].simpleName == 'Checkbox'}">
                    <x:Checkbox/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item2['class'].simpleName == 'DataList'}">
                    <x:DataList/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item2['class'].simpleName == 'Input'}">
                    <x:Input/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item2['class'].simpleName == 'Radiobutton'}">
                    <x:Radiobutton/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item2['class'].simpleName == 'Select'}">
                    <x:Select/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${item2['class'].simpleName == 'Textarea'}">
                    <x:Textarea/>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
</x:Form>
```

My problem is I can't be able to get the real name for the annotations. the result for `item2[class].simpleName` was something like `$Proxy55` (the numbers vary).

Anyone know how I can get the real name for the annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`. When you call `getClass()` on an `Annotation`, you'll get a proxy. You need to call `annotationType()` instead.

Change `item2[class].simpleName` to `item2.annotationType().simpleName`.